# Visual Basic: Radio button is visible even when I set it to visible = false

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
If bronzeRadioButton.checked = true then 
   tfRadioButton.visible = false And _
   SwimmingRadioButton.visible = false And _
   horseRadio button.visible = true 
End If
```

....I wanted to make the swimming radio button invisible, the tf radio button becomes invisible grand but swimming stays visible

Comment: VBA withn VisualStudio?

Comment: It would be easier to debug (and may even work better) to separate each of the `.visible = false` statements onto separate lines. Compacting code into one line usually gets me into trouble anyway.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks, but when I did that it still didn't work

Comment: Remove all the `And _`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please [edit] to clarify what is happening vs. what you want to happen.

Comment: Ok Kevin, So you have 4 radio buttons. If bronzeRadioButton is checked, what do you want to happen. Also, what actually happens, and if there are any errors what are they and on which line of code to they happen? Cheers - Have a look at these pages by the way - They're important. Thanks - [ask] and also [mcve]

Comment: You are running this code from an event, aren't you? The visibility won't just update on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up *comparison* and *assignment* operators, which are the same `=` token in VB.

Remove the `And`'s and make that 3 instructions, like this:

```
If bronzeRadioButton.checked = true then  'comparison
   tfRadioButton.visible = false 'assignment
   SwimmingRadioButton.visible = false 'assignment
   horseRadioButton.visible = true  'assignment
End If
```

Your code is really saying "if bronze radio button is checked, then false" ... or "then true" ...anyway the part after `Then` contains no *instructions*, just a Boolean expression. I'm surprised it even compiles at all.

---

**IF** I understand what you're asking, you could try this:

```
Dim isChecked As Boolean = bronzeRadioButton.Checked
tfRadioButton.Visible = Not isChecked
swimmingRadioButton.Visible = Not isChecked
horseRadioButton.Visible = isChecked
```

Comment: Thanks but it Still didn't work

Comment: @KevinFarrell edited.

Answer (score 1):

Does:

```
If bronzeRadioButton.Checked = True Then  
    tfRadioButton.Visible = False
    SwimmingRadioButton.Visible = False
    horseRadio button.Visible = True 
End If
```

not do what you need?